# Arabic word stress in the presence of an elided hamza ("hamzat al-waSl")

Tags: arabic

Word stress in classical Arabic follows a precise set of rules, which are described consistently in various Arabic grammar textbooks, e.g. Ryding's "A Reference Grammar of Modern Standard Arabic" (2005). However, none of the textbooks I have consulted describes what happens to the stress when the word starts with an elided hamza ("hamzat al-waSl").

Consider the following examples:

1. اقرا ***iq-ra'*** ("Read!" [2nd person, male])

   According to the rules, the first syllable should get the stress, however the presence of an elided hamza indicates that the "i" sound is auxiliary, so logically the stress should fall on the second syllable. Is this the case?
2. واقرا هذه الكليمات ***waq-ra'*** haa-dhi-hi l-ka-li-maa-ti ("... And read these words!" [2nd person, male])

   Unlike the first example, here the hamza actually gets elided. Where does the stress fall? If it falls on the first syllable, it means that the conjunction "and" gets the stress, but it seems unnatural that a particle would get the stress. So does the stress fall on the second syllable?
3. اب وابن ***a-bun wa-bnun*** ("A father and a son.")

   In this case both the first syllable and the second syllable (of both words) are auxiliary, so where do the stresses fall?
4. اخذت ابنا وذهبت a-khadh-tu **bnan** wa-dha-hab-tu ("I grabbed a son and walked away.")

   In this case the first syllable is elided, and the second syllable is auxiliary, so that the actual word is reduced to zero syllables. Where does the stress fall in this case?

Comment: Sorry but this question is offtopic, you may want to ask somewhere else.

Comment: @Mhmd: I see. Could you please suggest me a more appropriate place to ask this question?

Comment: There is currently an arabic proposal here: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/62022/arabic-language but you can ask somewhere out of the stackexchange network.

Comment: This would probably make an excellent tajwid question if the examples were all Qur'anic, rather than just generic Arabic sentences.